# Saving Video to MJPEG Format Locking Up Application

Tags: python

I am using a RPi camera to capture video in a MJPEG format to file. However, when I attempt to do so, the application freezes up and requires me to manually kill it. I am not sure why it is freezing up, but any ideas to resolve this problem would appreciated.

This program entails the following code in accord to the documentation from the following website under the section "start_recording": https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.start_recording

The actual program is as listed below:

```
 start_recording('/home/pi/testVideo.mjpeg', format = 'mjpeg')
 camera.wait_recording(5)
 stop_recording()
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 'camera.wait_recording(5)' ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. I was having to transcribe the code from my Raspberry Pi and could not just copy and paste. The issue seems to stem from the part of the format because .h264 files work just fine, but mjpegs don't work even though the documentation says that the mjpeg file type is compatible.